# boltdb не обрывается при systemd в режиме зависи

Tags: golang, файловая-система, systemd

Проблема такая если запускать go run ./*.go то все работает ок. Бд читает данные и записывает
Я пытаюсь запустить в режиме демона и там ошибка read-only . В документации болтдб есть сноска что в опцияъ можно поставить `ReadOnly:true` но так только чтение работать будет
Я как понял в режиме демона толи потоки не так идут толи я файл не правильно составил
вот мой systemd

```html
[Unit]
Description=1
Documentation=1
Wants=network.target
After=network.target
#CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_TIME
#PrivateTmp=yes

[Service]
Type=simple
DynamicUser=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/golang
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать

`DynamicUser=yes` данная опция служит для защиты файлов и работает в режиме read-only